# why `top` property is not overriden by another selector when targeting :after element

Tags: css

I have two rules that target the same element:

```
.tree-collapsed > .tree-label > .b-node-selector-widget__tree-node > span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 21px;
  display: block;
  border-left: 5px solid #616366;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

And another one overriding `top` property:

```
treecontrol treeitem > ul > li.tree-collapsed > div > .b-node-selector-widget__tree-node > span:after {
  top: 8px;
}
```

I can clearly see both of them applied to the element in Chrome tools:

[image]

But none overrides another one. I don't understand how that can be.

Comment: looks like a bug. not sure though. can you post your html and jsfiddle as well and which browser?

Comment: Shouldn't `treecontrol treeitem` be `.treecontrol .treeitem`?

Comment: [The first selector has a higher specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you calculate the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) you'll see that the first selector has a higher specificity

```
.tree-collapsed > .tree-label > .b-node-selector-widget__tree-node > span:after
```

has a specificity of `0-0-4-1`

```
treecontrol treeitem > ul > li.tree-collapsed > div > .b-node-selector-widget__tree-node > span:after
```

has a specificity of `0-0-3-6`

41 > 36, the first selector wins.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think it was the problem since properties overridden by specificity are shown crossed out in Chrome. Thanks!